# Is it bad SEO practice to have two almost-identical URLs?

Tags: seo, url

On my blog, after coding a function which trims stop words, I ended up with these two URLs which are identical if not for the post ID:

```
http://www.example.com/europe/france/597/june-weather-update

http://www.example.com/europe/france/997/june-weather-update
```

My platform - Wordpress - adds "-1", "-2", "-3" to the URLs when this happens but I removed it in my function. Now as I will have weather updates every year, it will be common for two or more links to be pretty much the same.

Would this cause any SEO issues? Please note that the content of the two pages is completely different, not related to each other.

Comment: User friendly / easy to remember - that is another matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this will not cause SEO issues. It is very common and normal for URLs to be similar as often times the only difference between URLs in an ID number of some kind. What matters is the content of these pages are different. It's when that starts to be very similar that you will run into issues.

Comment: I'd imagine that the similarity might cause problems here, since weather doesn't change that much on a year by year basis here in Europe. Would it be enough for a few digits to be different, or should the entire page be different?

Comment: As a matter of fact the data will be very similar, just a list of 30 days(the month of June) and the amount of rain collected. In the post, I of course intend to make the two introductory paragraphs different and add date and time but is it enough to call the two posts SEO-different?

Comment: Yes, that qualifies as different.

Comment: Are there any solid rules on what makes content "different"? Or is it just a trial and error process?

Comment: The [Google post on canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) gives a good indication of what makes content different versus duplicate.

Comment: The only SEO effect I can think of is CTR- you cannot remove the human part of search and if two URLs come up and they look too similar, the user may chose one or the other or even a competitors URL where the choice is clearer. It may confuse a user.

Comment: Dont focus _too_ much on SEO. It will become blatantly obvious and could hurt you sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

This will not directly hurt your SEO rankings. But consider this, other than the page content, you now have two pages "competing" for the same terms. You might want to manually help your page names out in cases like this. For example 2014-june-weather-update and 2013-june-weather-update would likely help users and SE alike to distinguish what your pages are about. (this is just an example, I don't know the details of your pages)

Comment: Yes John, what you says makes sense. Funnily enough I was also considering adding "extra" data to the URL, and the year is of course what I thought about as well.